# Missing artifact org.glassfish.jersey.media:jaxrs-media-moxy:jar:2.16 in Maven project in Eclipse ,what to do?

Tags: maven, jersey, jax-rs, pom.xml, moxy

I have added dependency for `jersey-media-moxy` in `pom.xml`,but I am getting

> Missing artifact org.glassfish.jersey.media:jaxrs-media-moxy:jar:2.16

error message in `pom.xml`.

I have added necessary jar file to my build path.I have also updated the maven project using  Force update ,still i am getting errors in the `pom.xml`.

Comment: Where is your pom.xml? Where is the error from maven?

Comment: This is my pom.xml

Comment: Can you please edit your post and put the pom.xml? Also, can you clarify "error message in pom.xml", is the error coming from an IDE? Is it an error when running maven? If it is with maven, which command did you use? The more details you give, the better we can understand the root cause of the issue

Comment: Should be `jersey-media-moxy` not `jaxrs-media-moxy`

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-moxy -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
</dependency>
that would do the job for you!
happy coding...
```